# Can't acces to 'accounts' from a Facebook Profile ID

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't get a response to the event 'accounts' of a Facebook profile that is associated with my application, this in order to get the list of IDs of Pages and Groups to which you belong and then show them to indicate what you want to publish from my platform.

We have active the permission: managed_page

The query I make the API with my code is as follows:

- /User_Profile_ID/accounts?access_token=Hash_Token
- Method: get
- Error: Server error (not reponse).

The code is:

```
$place= 'accounts';
$method= 'get';
$theuser= secure_postget($_POST["nickname"]); # form select (from a users list).
$fbuser= query_db( "USERS", "ID='". $theuser. "'", "FACEBOOK_ID"); # query mysql: get the Facebook ID
$fbtoken= '?access_token='query_db( "USERS", "ID='". $theuser. "'", "FACEBOOK_TOKEN"); # query mysql: get the Facebook Token
$r= $fb->api( '/'. $fbuser. '/'. $place.$fbtoken, $method );
return $r;
```

Regards !

Comment: how are you getting the user access token for each query?

Comment: the user access token is get from the synchronization between Facebook Profile and APP Facebook ?.... Then the token is saved in the DB !... **'query_db'** is a own function to connect and query to mysql. **"FACEBOOK_ID"** is a cell in my db with the Profile ID, and **"FACEBOOK_TOKEN"** the token obtained in the synchronization.

Comment: if I change the query by 'feed', I obtain the 'Feed' from the user !... what's failing ?, why isn't work with 'accounts' ?

Comment: Have you tryed to debug the tokens that are failing for you, i ask this because access_tokens expire after about 2 hours.?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

also what version of the sdk are you authenticating users with?

Comment: I found how to access to information of 'accounts', the problem was that called my script like this: "http://misitioweb.com/test.php", and was to be with 'www' at the beginning. How I can make my APP to do the query without running the 'www' or other subdomain?

Comment: The last thing i could think of whilst laying in bed last night, did you set your domain settings for your app to www., if so it would treat it as a subdomain and could possibly stop the sdk from working from the normal domain.

Answer (score 0):

Query for user accounts via php sdk 3.1.1.  A valid user access token is required to request user accounts.

**query by "me" sesson.**

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if($user){
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
}else{
   // no user, no token - reauth or redirect 
}
if($access_token){
   $user_accounts = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,accounts.fields(id,name,link,picture)&return_ssl_resources=1');
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($user_accounts).'</pre>';
```

**query by user id.**

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
if($user){
   $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
}else{
   // no user, no token - reauth or redirect 
}
if($access_token){
   $user_accounts = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'?fields=id,name,accounts.fields(id,name,link,picture)&return_ssl_resources=1');
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($user_accounts).'</pre>';
```

Comment: it's ok... my querys to Api facebook are fine too !